# positioning table inline with text

Tags: tables, inline

I have following piece of code:

```
\section{Skills}
\begin{CV}
\item[Computing:] C/C++, Python and Matlab
\item[CAD Tools:] GNU Radio, Xilinx ISE, Active HDL, MikroC, Keil uVision, Altium Designer, Cadence VIRTUOSO
\item[Languages:] AAA
\begin{table}[h] %\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}>{\bfseries}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}}
& German  & native \\
& French  & near native \\
& Dutch & near native\\
& Italian & fair \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{CV}
\pagebreak
```

The problem is that table with the languages is placed in the way that top and bottom of the table is equally distanted from the line of the item title. i want top left corner of the table to be in the place where would be the first letter of the normaln item text.

Thanks

Comment: What is the `CV` environment? This code is not compilable as is. On another hand, I don't think you should let your table float, and so you should suppress your table environment.

Answer (score 16):

Remove the `\begin{table}[h] %\centering`  and `\end{table}`
as you do not want a float and use

```
AAA \begin{tabular}[t]{p{2cm}>{\bfseries}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}}
```

Then the first row of the table will share a baseline with AAA

Comment: The same works for the tabular* environment, but then the optional argument has to go in the second position as in `\begin{tabular*}{6cm}[t]{p{2cm}>{\bfseries}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}}`. I thought this might be useful to know for some people.